# Is there a way to skip over rows when error encountered whilst loading data from CSV? (Error code: 1261)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I am using MySQL to load 10million+ rows into a database from a CSV file. Unfortunately it is returning an error every time I attempt it ("Row 3816836 doesn't contain data for all columns"). I have downloaded software that can visualise large CSV's, and from what I can see, there is nothing wrong with the data. There are missing values in some columns (as are there in most of the millions of rows successfully loaded). The table is set for NULL default values. So I'm at a complete loss as to how to successfully load the data.

Is there a way to skip over this one row!? Any error handling during loading would be HUGELY appreciated.

```
USE data;
LOAD DATA INFILE "data.csv"
INTO TABLE master
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

Comment: There is no official way to skip that. I assume that line contains wrong data and because of this it's couldn't be inserted. Could you add the create table DDL and the bogus row of that csv with some other rows previous and after of that as a sample? I think there is a magic / hidden or probably an unescaped character around of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is not technically a resolution to the Q I asked, I have in the short term solved the issue. I used Python to extract the row, and added two separate CSV's (before and after the problem row). Able to look at the problem row, it seemed to be because of a lone "/". Removing this enabled me to add that row in individually.

It's one way to solve it!